# Aggregation of data in mongodb collections

Tags: mongodb, relationship

in my current project I've got structure like:

```
 -
   event_id: 1
   attr1: val1
   attr2: val2
   topics:
     -
       topic_id: 1
       attr1: val1
     -
       topic_id: 2
       attr1: val2
 -
   event_id: 2
   attr1: val3
   attr2: val4
   topics:
     - topic_id: 1
       attr1: val7
     -
       topic_id: 3
       attr1: val6
     - 
       topic_id: 4
       attr1: val8
```

I need to be able to present data in two alternative views:

```
{ event_id: 1, attr1: val1, attr2: val2, topic_count: 2 },
{ event_id: 2, attr1: val3, attr2: val4, topic_count: 3 }
```

And:

```
{ topic_id: 1, event_id: 2, event_attr1: val3,  e: [ { event_id: 1, e1_attr... }, { event_id: 2, e_attr... } ], t_attr... },
{ topic_id: 2, event_id: 1, e_attr1: val1,  e: [ { event_id: 1, e1_attr... } ], t_attr... },
{ topic_id: 3, event_id: 2, e_attr1: val3, e: [ { event_id: 2, e2_attr... } ], t_attr... },
{ topic_id: 4, event_id: 2, e_attr1: val3, e: [ { event_id: 2, e2_attr... } ], t_attr... }
```

I am using aggregation pipeline to achieve this structure, and it works fine, but mongo gets slow and memory hungry when using sorting, filtering and pagination on bigger data sets. One of ideas was to create second redundant structure like (with attributes, omited bellow):

```
-
  t_id: 1
  e:
  -
    e_id: 1
  -
    e_id: 2
-
  t_id: 2
  -
    e_id: 1
-
  t_id: 3
  -
    e_id: 2
-
  t_id: 4
  -
    e_id: 2
```

And update both collections simultaneously on every write. Other way was filtering collection both before and after $project and $unwind, but that makes writing filters more difficult.

Another approach I've been considering was making flat list, like:

```
{ event_id: 1, topic_id: 1, event1_attrs: ... , topic1_attrs: ... },
{ event_id: 1, topic_id: 2, event1_attrs: ... , topic2_attrs: ... },
{ event_id: 2, topic_id: 1, event2_attrs: ... , topic1_attrs: ... },
{ event_id: 2, topic_id: 3, event2_attrs: ... , topic3_attrs: ... },
{ event_id: 2, topic_id: 4, event2_attrs: ... , topic4_attrs: ... }
```

But I'm bit afraid of grouping performance.

Does any of those approaches makes any sense, or is emulating searchable, sortable and paginable many2many relationship in mongodb utterly stupid and unachievable on larger data sets? I'm browsing web searching answer on that question, and I found lots of voices weighing both sides.

Comment: Can you widen the scope of your problem? E.g. if you make the aggregation query on each request, and the query is slow, you can solve the problem in some way. But if your problem is that overall the query is slow, you need another solution. I mean describe the whole use case you currently have.

Comment: My starting point was relationship of two collections: first with events, second with topics. Both has own attributes, and I need to:
1. sort and filter Events collection by all of its attributes
2. sort and filter Topics collection by all of its  attributes and by all of Events attributes
Current structure seemed to be most logical - but writing implementation I see many downfalls, eg. to see most recent version of any Topic I need to use $group and $unwind, and then sort/filter/paginate it, and then after $group/$unwind I don't have any indexes anymore.

Comment: You are right, but what I am asking is what is the frequency of the query?

Comment: Most painful query is not generated very often - perhaps couple dozen times a day, but problem is, query often needs to return data immediately - so preparing data in background would be problematic. Other queries can be limited before any grouping, but some shoud work on full dataset (or at least quite big subset).

Comment: In that case the only thing I can suggest is to use the `$out` option of aggregation pipeline, to accumulate data in background. You are right, in the middle you lose your indexes, thus you have to point of optimisation. So you can measure the average duration of the query, and schedule a background job, and output the result into a separate collection. Then just show the result as a static data.